# Attempt to invoke virtual method FAB button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, floating-action-button

recently in my project I wanted to add the Floating Action Button button feature to the main activity, but after I added the function to the main activity, the app crashed and errors appeared.

logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ainuralizar.firebaseproject, PID: 13371
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ainuralizar.firebaseproject/com.ainuralizar.firebaseproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3333)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)

     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.ainuralizar.firebaseproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
```

this is my FAB part

```
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    Adapter adapter;
    List<Model> models;
    Integer[] colors = null;
    ArgbEvaluator argbEvaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();

    DatabaseReference mRef;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private FloatingActionButton fab_main, fab1_mail, fab2_share;
    private Animation fab_open, fab_close, fab_clock, fab_anticlock;
    TextView textview_mail, textview_share;

    Boolean isOpen = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
//        innerDataModelsMenu1ForAdapter = new ArrayList<>();
//        innerDataModelsMenu2ForAdapter = new ArrayList<>();

        models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sample1, "Menu1", "THIS IS MENU 1"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sample2, "Menu2", " THIS IS MENU 2"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sample3, "Menu3", " THIS IS MENU 3"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sample4, "Menu4", " THIS IS MENU 4"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sample5, "Menu5", " THIS IS MENU 5"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sample6, "Menu6", " THIS IS MENU 6"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sample7, "Menu7", " THIS IS MENU 6"));

        adapter = new Adapter(models, this);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPadding(130, 0, 130, 0);

        Integer[] colors_temp = {getResources().getColor(R.color.color1), getResources().getColor(R.color.color2), getResources().getColor(R.color.color3), getResources().getColor(R.color.color4), getResources().getColor(R.color.color5), getResources().getColor(R.color.color6), getResources().getColor(R.color.color7)};

        colors = colors_temp;

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                if (position < (adapter.getCount() - 1) && position < (colors.length - 1)) {
                    viewPager.setBackgroundColor(

                            (Integer) argbEvaluator.evaluate(positionOffset, colors[position], colors[position + 1])
                    );
                } else {
                    viewPager.setBackgroundColor(colors[colors.length - 1]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        fab_main = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab1_mail = findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        fab2_share = findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
        fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
        fab_clock = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_rotate_clock);
        fab_anticlock = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_rotate_anticlock);

        textview_mail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_mail);
        textview_share = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_share);

        fab_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isOpen) {
                    textview_mail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    textview_share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    fab2_share.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab1_mail.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab_main.startAnimation(fab_anticlock);
                    fab2_share.setClickable(false);
                    fab1_mail.setClickable(false);
                    isOpen = false;
                } else {
                    textview_mail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textview_share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab2_share.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab1_mail.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab_main.startAnimation(fab_clock);
                    fab2_share.setClickable(true);
                    fab1_mail.setClickable(true);
                    isOpen = true;
                }
            }
        });

        fab2_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        fab1_mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is my fab XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="186dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:background="#212121"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_share" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:background="#212121"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_email" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have seen several related posts but nothing has worked yet,

sorry I'm just a beginner, which part should I change?

Comment: Did you add the floating action buttons to your main activity layout?

Comment: Do you have all these buttons with ids `fab`, `fab1`, `fab2` in your layout file?

Comment: i have declared buttons and id in my layout sir ,but its still not worked

Comment: Please post this layout, since the error is saying those views don't exist.

Comment: Please post your whole of MainActivity, not an excerpt.